# How to Create a CircularProgress in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-progressbar

I code in `Xamarin.Android` and now I need a `Circular ProgressBar` to show the actual progress. I am not talking about the `ProgressBar` spinners, they only indicate that a process is running, but not the actual progress.

I have found some libraries, but those are exclusively for `Java Android`. For `Xamarin` I only found the `RadialProgress` library but it is not as customizable as I need.

Thanks.

I want something like that:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pack `Java Android` library you found into a Xamarin Binding and then just reference it in your `Xamarin.Android` project as a regular Xamarin.Android library and start using the component you like.

You can read more about [Xamarin Bindings here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/)